# How I can patch a private method of a delphi class?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have read these questions and answers

[How to change the implementation (detour) of an externally declared function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905287/how-to-change-the-implementation-detour-of-anexternally-declared-function)

[Patch routine call in delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978177/patch-routine-call-in-delphi)

but i can't figere out how patch a **private method** of a class located in anoher unit.

Check this sample I want to patch the `Bar` procedure.

```
Unit ThidParty;
Interface
   Type
      TFoo =Class
        private
           procedure Bar;
       end;
```

I think which the key is find a way to obtain the address of the private method.

So, How I can patch a private method of a delphi class?

Comment: AFAIK this is NOT possible since private methods/procedure are NOT part of the VMT and thus are not available via RTTI etc. It might be possible to hack this but this would need you to disassemble the other unit and then do some pointer arithmetic plus some assembly to get there...

Comment: See also [Access a strict protected property of a Delphi class?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8330615/576719). Class Helpers as mentioned by David.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The solution outlined below works for versions up to and including Delphi Seattle.
You can use a [class helper](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Class_and_Record_Helpers) to crack the class:

**Unit1**

```
type
  TTest = class
  private
    procedure Foo;
  end;
```

**Unit2**

```
type
  TMyTestHelper = class helper for TTest
    function GetFooAddress: Pointer;
  end;

function TMyTestHelper.GetFooAddress: Pointer;
var
  MethodPtr: procedure of object;
begin
  MethodPtr := Self.Foo;
  Result := TMethod(MethodPtr).Code;
end;

function FooAddress: Pointer;
begin
  Result := TTest(nil).GetFooAddress;//don't need to instantiate an object
end;
```

Pass the return value from `FooAddress` to one of your patching functions and you are golden.

However, starting with Delphi 10.1 Berlin, this no longer works! Class helpers can no longer access strict protected, strict private or private members. This "feature" was actually a compiler bug that Embarcadero has now fixed in Berlin. You are out of luck.

Comment: Isn't that a hole in the compiler? What if it gets fixed?

Comment: @Andreas It's by design I think. Class helpers are meant to have access to privates. If it gets 'fixed' then you'll have to use other means to crack the privates.

Comment: @David: If the class is in a unit that is in another package, the compiler may not have generated an export symbol for the private method, thus the code would fail.

Comment: @Andreas that would be compile time failure right? I never use packages myself.

Comment: @David: Unfortunatly not. The DCP contains the private symbol but it isn't exported in the BPL. So the compiler would be happy to compile it but at runtime your application wouldn't start due to a missing symbol. That's why this is a hole in the compiler.

Comment: @AndreasHausladen Are there any specific circumstances for this to happen because I cannot reproduce it for either Delphis own packages (made a class helper for TButton and accessed a private member and used runtime packages and it worked) nor with some own package where I did the same (class with private method accessed by a class helper in the host application)

Comment: @Stefan: I stand corrected. It looks like the compiler really exports all private methods in a BPL.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Hi David, I've just found your code which looks just the trick I'm looking for.  However I'm getting an Access Violation on the line MethodPtr := Self.Foo;  Is this not because no object has been instantiated?  I'm using Delphi XE6.

Comment: @Jonathan I don't think so. I bet your code has some other variation. After all, the code in my answer clearly doesn't instantiate an object.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  Ok thanks.  My code does vary in that my 'foo' method is a function rather than procedure so I'm declaring MethodPtr as function(Request: THttpRequest): THttpResponse of object.

Comment: That should not matter. Is the private virtual?

Comment: Ah, the method I'm referencing is overriding a method in it's parent which is marked as virtual; abstract;

Comment: @JonathanWareham Yeah, that's a whole different ball game

Comment: I've got it to work by creating a temporary object to use to call GetFooAddress to get the address and then free it.  All appears to work fine but not sure if there are any side effects?

Comment: Well, there's likely a cleaner way to detour a virtual. Why not modify the VMT?

Comment: It was considered a bug and from Delphi 10.1 Berlin it is no longer possible to access private members with class helpers.

Comment: Ok, there is still a possible solution: `TMethod(MethodPtr).Code := @TTest.Foo;`

Answer (score 0):

Just Redefine the methode using Class interception , it work until Rad 10.4

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).