# Monkey patching methods (functions) in Delphi Win64

Tags: delphi, monkeypatching

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156430/how-i-can-patch-a-private-method-of-a-delphi-class), I have successfully patched a strict private (!) function in Delphi 32bits using the [Delphi Detours Library](https://github.com/MahdiSafsafi/delphi-detours-library/tree/master/Source) and following code:

```
var
  Trampoline_TFormStyleHook_GetBorderSize : function (Self: TFormStyleHook) : TRect;

  type
   TFormStyleHookFix = class helper for TFormStyleHook
     function GetBorderSizeAddr: Pointer;
   end;

function TFormStyleHookFix.GetBorderSizeAddr: Pointer;
var
  MethodPtr: function: TRect of object;
begin
  with Self do MethodPtr := GetBorderSize;
  Result := TMethod(MethodPtr).Code;
end;

function Detour_TFormStyleHook_GetBorderSize(Self: TFormStyleHook): TRect;
begin
  Result := Trampoline_TFormStyleHook_GetBorderSize(Self);
  if (Screen.PixelsPerInch > 96) then
    Result.Top := MulDiv(Result.Top, 96, Screen.PixelsPerInch);
end;

initialization
 Trampoline_TFormStyleHook_GetBorderSize :=
   InterceptCreate(TFormStyleHook(nil).GetBorderSizeAddr,
   @Detour_TFormStyleHook_GetBorderSize)
finalization
 InterceptRemove(@Trampoline_TFormStyleHook_GetBorderSize);
```

Whilst this works fine in Win32, it fails in Win64. The interception works but statement `Result := Trampoline_TFormStyleHook_GetBorderSize(Self)` returns trash.  I guess this is because  `function (Self: TFormStyleHook) : TRect` is not equivalent to `function: TRect of object` in Win64.  Does anyone have an idea about how to make the above work in Win64.  I am using Delphi Rio, but it works the same with Delphi Tokyo.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind.  I found the answer.  The following works with both win32 and win64. As suspected `function (Self: TFormStyleHook) : TRect` is not equivalent to `function: TRect of object` in Win64.  You need to declare the Trampoline function as `function: TRect of object` and use the cast to TMethod to set/get the code pointer.

```
  type
   TGetBorderSize = function: TRect of object;

   TFormStyleHookFix = class helper for TFormStyleHook
     function GetBorderSizeAddr: Pointer;
     function Detour_GetBorderSize: TRect;
   end;

var
  Trampoline_TFormStyleHook_GetBorderSize : TGetBorderSize;
  Detour_TFormStyleHook_GetBorderSize : TGetBorderSize;

function TFormStyleHookFix.GetBorderSizeAddr: Pointer;
var
  MethodPtr: TGetBorderSize;
begin
  with Self do MethodPtr := GetBorderSize;
  Result := TMethod(MethodPtr).Code;
end;

function TFormStyleHookFix.Detour_GetBorderSize: TRect;
var
  MethodPtr: TGetBorderSize;
begin
  TMethod(MethodPtr).Code := TMethod(Trampoline_TFormStyleHook_GetBorderSize).Code;
  TMethod(MethodPtr).Data := Pointer(Self);
  Result := MethodPtr;
  if (Screen.PixelsPerInch > 96) then
    Result.Top := MulDiv(Result.Top, 96, Screen.PixelsPerInch);
end;

initialization
 Detour_TFormStyleHook_GetBorderSize := TFormStyleHook(nil).Detour_GetBorderSize;
 TMethod(Trampoline_TFormStyleHook_GetBorderSize).Code :=
   InterceptCreate(TFormStyleHook(nil).GetBorderSizeAddr,
   TMethod(Detour_TFormStyleHook_GetBorderSize).Code)
finalization
 InterceptRemove(TMethod(Trampoline_TFormStyleHook_GetBorderSize).Code);
```

Comment: The Trampoline and the detour functions are functions of object instead of procedures.  As suspected - function (Self: TFormStyleHook) : TRect - is not equivalent to - function: TRect of object - in Win64

Comment: Put that explanation into your answer, not  buried in comments.

Comment: @KenWhite  I did that.